# Нейросеть для раскраски ЧБ изображений красит все в один цвет

Tags: машинное-обучение, tensorflow, pytorch

Обучаю модель предсказывать две цветовые компоненты H и S цветового пространства HSV(Hue, Saturation, Value, как LAB, только меньше). На вход подается V-компонента, она же ЧБ изображение.
Нейросеть в конечном итоге обучается красить все в один цвет, обычно в зеленом оттенке, но бывает и красный, и серый. На примере ошибка не меняется, но бывает скачет туда-обратно в небольшом диапазоне. Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Архитектура GAN:

```
Дискриминатор: 
три сверточных блока, разделенные ReLU. Один сверточный блок - это две 
свертки 3х3 подряд.

Генератор: 
4 сверточных блока энкодера, где каждый блок - это две свертки 3х3, разделенные ReLU. 
Каждый блок заканчивается BatchNorm. Размер латентного пространства 512х8х8.
4 блока ConvTranspose декодера, где каждый блок - две свертки 3х3, разделенные ReLU.
Каждый блок заканчивается BatchNorm. На выходе 32 канала.
И в конце одна свертка, которая формирует на выходе 2 канала H и S.

    self.l1_encoder = torch.nn.Sequential(
        
        collections.OrderedDict({
            'conv1': torch.nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 1, out_channels = 64, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 64, out_channels = 64, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1, stride = 2),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
            ),
            'conv2': torch.nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 64, out_channels = 128, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 128, out_channels = 128, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1, stride = 2),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
            ),
            'conv3': torch.nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 128, out_channels = 256, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 256, out_channels = 256, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1, stride = 2),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(), 
                torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            ),
            'conv4': torch.nn.Sequential(            
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 256, out_channels = 512, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 512, out_channels = 512, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1, stride = 2),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(512)
            )
        })
    )
    self.l2_decoder = torch.nn.Sequential(
        
        collections.OrderedDict({
            'convTranspose1': torch.nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels = 512, out_channels = 512, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels = 512, out_channels = 256, kernel_size = 3, stride = 2, padding = 1, output_padding = 1),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(256)
            ),
            'convTranspose2': torch.nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels = 512, out_channels = 256, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels = 256, out_channels = 128, kernel_size = 3, stride = 2, padding = 1, output_padding = 1),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            ),
            'convTranspose3': torch.nn.Sequential(            
                torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels = 256, out_channels = 128, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels = 128, out_channels = 64, kernel_size = 3, stride = 2, padding = 1, output_padding = 1),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            ),
            'convTranspose4': torch.nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels = 128, out_channels = 64, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels = 64, out_channels = 32, kernel_size = 3, stride = 2, padding = 1, output_padding = 1),
                torch.nn.LeakyReLU(),
                torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            ),
            'convOut': torch.nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 32, out_channels = 2, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
                torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(2),
                torch.nn.Sigmoid()
            )
        })    
    )
```

Оптимизатор Adam, ошибка BCELoss.

Пробовал:

- разные архитектуры: U-Net, GAN U-Net, обыкновенный сверточный автоэнкодер, автоэнкодер с VGG в качестве энкодера, U-Net с VGG в качестве энкодера.
- разные параметры оптимизатора, а так же оптимизатор AdaDelta, добавлял L2-регуляризацию.
- разные функции потерь.
- разные функции активации.
- разные наборы данных(до 10000), imageNet(50000).
- много чего еще

Я так понимаю модель падает в некий локальный минимум, усреднить все одним цветом. Как из него выбраться идеи закончились.
Добавлю еще, что на одном изображении модель учится (само собой переобучается).

Примеры архитектур: github.com/edgar32801work/stylerNet/